# Share Android SDK between Xamarin Studio and Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is it possible to install and point both Xamarin Studio and Android Studio to a same location for Android SDK, this is just so I could save some space on my Mac. I plan to install both studios, but I thought I would ask if doing so would bring me trouble down the road.

Comment: Start the SDK Manager from Android Studio and from Xamarin Studio, and compare the location of the Android SDK in each. What do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can share the Android SDK between both installs.

In this case I installed Xamarin Studio first (and thus the various Android SDKs):

[image]

I then installed Android Studio and during the install selected the same Android SDK location:

[image]

You can of course go the other way...

Comment: Thank you and I was able to do it the other way too.

Comment: Can we do the same thing for Visual Studio and Android Studio on windows?

Comment: @ChetanMehra Yes, I do it on macOS and Windows, just set the SDK location to the same directory.